# try to replace my text with all the lists

Tags: python

I have a text `"abc"` or I replaced the characters in list named `al` with list `key2`. let's assume that I don't know what list I have replaced the characters with and that I would like the program to try to replace my text with all the lists.

```
al = ['a','b','c']

key1 = ['0','1','2']

key2 = ['2','3','4']

key3 = ['4','5','6']

lk = [key1,key2,key3]

text = '234'

for j in range(2):
    for i in range(2):
        text = text.replace(str(lk[i]),al[i])
    print(text)

'''
for i in range(2):
    text = text.replace(al[i],key1[i])
    print(text)
    
for i in range(2):
    text = text.replace(al[i],key2[i])
    print(text)
    
for i in range(2):
    text = text.replace(al[i],key3[i])
    print(text)

'''
```

Comment: please provide the your sample input and your expected output

Comment: '123' to 'abc' provided you do not know with which key to replace the characters

Comment: how these keys defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of python

```
  

decoder_dict ={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}

user_input = str(input("Enter your number: "))

output = []
for num in user_input.split():
  output.append(decoder_dict[int(num)])

print(''.join(output))
```